# Napili Community: Filter Groups List Based on Custom Criteria?

Tags: community, filters, napili, collaborationgroup

> **Problem:** Our Napili (Customer Service) community site utilizes custom components and
>   Salesforce's out-of-the-box "Page Variations" functionality to render
>   different page variations and different content to different sets of
>   users who access our community based on profile, custom conditions,
>   etc.
>
> We are trying to implement Groups into our community, but have been
>   unable to find any resources/documentation/other posts related to
>   FILTERING these group lists to hide certain groups from certain user
>   sets. We ideally need to be able to Categorize our groups into a minimum of 2 different categories, and display only a certain category of community groups to one user set, and the other to a different user set, but I am unable to find many customization options available for group object(s).

---

As of Spring '16, we've been able to add Groups to our Napili (Now called Customer Service) based communities, see Salesforce Release Docs:

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_networks_templates_groups_napili.htm

However, my attempts to implement so far have been less-than-welcoming, as it appears that the Groups List page and standard component have no options for customization, no addition of new List Views, no re-ordering of List View priority, or pretty much any functionality at all that would allow me to show certain groups to certain sets of community users based on user criteria:

[image]

---

I've read every piece of documentation I can find on the subject, done many searches on Google and Stack, and ultimately haven't gotten any closer to solving this problem without considering writing a completely custom Group List component. I don't even see a way to add custom fields to group creation (which I would want to use in order to create Group "Categories" for filtering purposes)

> **Question:** Am I missing some key functionality either within Salesforce or within Communities that would allow for the creation of
>   custom fields/modification of list views, specifically as it relates
>   to showing certain groups to certain sets of users based on profile?
>   Or will I have to come up with something custom, possibly utilizing
>   specific naming conventions for the groups and then building lists by
>   looping through groups that contain the naming convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear you will have to go down the custom path and there is not much you can do with the standard components provided .

The other workaround can be to keep the groups visibility to private ,that way you can only approve only certain users and then access the related content .

Comment: I might be wrong but I believe the documentation says somewhere that even with the groups visibility set to private, they can still be seen by guest users but will prompt for login credentials when trying to access the group. If this is true, wouldn't be ideal because I don't want them seeing the groups **at all*. I suppose I have no choice, custom it is. Do you happen to have any experience with Community Groups? Can I add custom fields to them somehow for category/filtering purposes?

Comment: They can see only group name but wont be able to see feeds and members of the group .You cannot add custom fields to groups .